# Unity Facebook Canvas Inapp Purchase Error

Tags: facebook, facebook-canvas

I've been trying to make the facebook canvas inapp api working for my game virtual items for quite some time without any success. 
Its unity made game running in facebook canvas iframe with WebGL.

I am using the following code to make the transaction...

```
FB.Canvas.Pay (product: "productID",
            quantity: 1,
            callback: delegate(IPayResult response) {
                Debug.Log (response.RawResult);
                if(onProductPurchasedSucceed != null) {
                    if( response.ResultDictionary["status"] == "completed"){    
                        onProductPurchasedSucceed("productID");
                    }
                }
            }
        );
```

When I invoke this method from canvas page.. This is what I ended up with

[image]

[image]

Since its a simple game I chose facebook hosted feature to upload my game assets. I have no idea what to fill in App Domains field.
I tried to setup apps.facebook.com, but its not accepting

Comment: Good question, I see anything in this regard mentioned in the Simply Application Hosting documentation. I’d try and use browser dev tools to find out where the content is loaded from.

Comment: instead of sending hardcoded product id, should I load the product details from a url? App Domain field expecting that url domain ?

Comment: No, I think it expects the domain where the content is actually loaded from. And when you use Simply Application Hosting, that is presumably some Facebook URL.

Comment: any updates on this issue?

Comment: Well kinda waiting on you here to report what the result was of you trying out what I suggested already.